# How does groovy's addBatch(map) work for Sql.withBatch?

Tags: groovy, groovy-sql

I'm trying to call [`groovy.sql.Sql.batch`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#withBatch(int,java.lang.String,groovy.lang.Closure)) from a statically typed language.

I succeed in calling `addBatch` on the callback object `ps` with a parameter of type `List`. This works well for statements like `insert into TABLENAME(a, b, c) values (?, ?, ?)`.

To cite the documentation:

```
Named parameters (into maps or domain objects) are also supported:

def updateCounts = sql.withBatch(20, 'insert into TABLENAME(a, b, c) values (:foo, :bar, :baz)') { ps ->
    ps.addBatch([foo:10, bar:12, baz:5])  // map
    ps.addBatch(foo:7, bar:3, baz:98)     // Groovy named args allow outer brackets to be dropped
    ...
}
```

So, I thought to also support using batch updates for Maps. The problem is, that the callback parameter of type [BatchingPreparedStatementWrapper](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/BatchingPreparedStatementWrapper.html) does not provide a method `addBatch(Map)`, but only overloads `addBatch(Object[])`, `addBatch(List)`, `addBatch(String)`.

How can `Sql.withBatch` be used with Map parameters from kotlin or java? And how does it actually work in groovy without throwing NoSuchMethodError, MissingMethodException or whatever?

Comment: could you show javadoc for java addBatch(map)?

Comment: @dagget: Just click the hyperlink labeled  `BatchingPreparedStatementWrapper`. There is no addBatch(Map). Just addBatch(List).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in groovy following code:

```
def f(Object[] p){
    println p
}


f( a:1, b:2, c:3 )
```

works fine and prints:

```
[[a:1, b:2, c:3]]
```

so, if you have function `f(Object[] x)`, then `f(a:123)` equals to `f( [ [a:123] ] )`

this means that from java following should work:

```
Map params = new HashMap();
params.put("a", 123);

ps.addBatch( new Object[]{ params } );
```

Comment: Wow. Works like a charm! singletonList containing the map does the trick